# rookie q: how to plot R Shiny sliderInputs

Tags: r, shiny

I want to **barPlot the input values of 2 sliders** in my shiny web app. As the original code is lengthy I included a shortened example of what I am trying to build below.

The bars in the chart are supposed to be the values of the sliderInputs S1 and S2, but for that I would need to include them as a **vector** which I can´t figure out how to do. The code as below returns the error "object input ID not found" instead of displaying the barplot.

As I just started with Shiny I am still trying to properly understand reactive(), so please excuse my rookie attempt.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated - thanks a lot!

```
library(shiny)


data <- reactive(c({input$S1; input$S2}))
    

ui <- fluidPage(
    br(),
    sliderInput(inputId = "S1", label= "S1", min = 1, max = 10, value = 5),
    br(),
    sliderInput(inputId = "S2", label= "S2", min = 1, max = 10, value = 5),
    br(),
    plotOutput("P1", width = "40vw")
    
)



server <- function(input, output) {
    

    output$P1 <- renderPlot({
        barplot(data(), horiz=TRUE, names.arg=c("S2", "S1"))
    })


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You cannot refer to S2 and S1 like that. You need input$S1 and input$S2

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise which part you are referring to?

Comment: Please check the [documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/basics.html). When you use the input you need to add input$, so that is in the barplot comment what I am refering to. But again, this is all explained in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I read through the whole thing already. I still don´t understand what you mean, sorry!

Are you referring to the names.arg in the barplot? Because that is not the problem.

Comment: It kind of is. Again it is all described in the documentation (there literally is a section "Reactive Programming Basics"), that you need reactive in your server etc. Also, in this example it doesn't make sense (and highly overcomplicates) refering to the data rather than just the input.

Comment: Indeed I have moved reactive() to the server function already.

But if I just enter a vector of some numbers for the height argument of the barplot, the names show up correctly, so I don´t understand how this would cause problem - would be much appreciated if you could explain!

Also, if I get what you are saying correctly, you can refer to the inputs in barplot without having a reactive?

Sorry if this is not well done I just started learning R.

Comment: Did you also read the documentation on how to put the brackets? Because just moving it isn't going to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, make sure you read documentation on which brackets to use where, which signs you need to use where ( `c()` doesnt work with `;`) and where to put the reactive statements/refer to the inputs.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    br(),
    sliderInput(inputId = "S1", label= "S1", min = 1, max = 10, value = 5),
    br(),
    sliderInput(inputId = "S2", label= "S2", min = 1, max = 10, value = 5),
    br(),
    plotOutput("P1", width = "40vw")
    
)



server <- function(input, output) {
    
    data <- reactive({ c(input$S1, input$S2) })
    
    output$P1 <- renderPlot({
        barplot(data(), horiz=TRUE, names.arg=c("S2", "S1"))
    })
    
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```